# lsbk issue, reboot causes devices to re-order

Tags: centos, mappeddrive

I am having a weird issue with lsblk and my nvme devices. This occurs on CentOS 7.7, 7.8, 8.2

On first boot after installation the devices are ordered as expected under lsbk

```
[root@pqclient-1-127 ~]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0  600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:3    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:4    0  1.8T  0 part
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─cl-swap 253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─cl-home 253:2    0  1.8T  0 lvm  /home
nvme1n1     259:1    0  1.8T  0 disk
```

After reboot nvme1n1 (2nd NVMe device) gets changed to 259:0 and nvme0n1 (first NVMe device) is changed to 259:1

```
[root@pqclient-1-127 ~]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme1n1     259:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
nvme0n1     259:1    0  1.8T  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0  600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:3    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:4    0  1.8T  0 part
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─cl-swap 253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─cl-home 253:2    0  1.8T  0 lvm  /home
```

I suspect some kind of hardware issue but does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Numbering of Linux `nvme*` or `sd*` devices is not stable, the order has no particular guarantee. Storage systems may have race conditions in how they are discovered, or the physical paths to devices may change.

[Persistent device names](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/persistent_naming) are available as various symlinks under `/dev/disk/by*`

Or, you are using LVM. You can see volumes by name with LVM tools, like  `pvs; vgs; lvs;`  Doesn't show non-LVM boot partitions, or major/minor numbers, but those are not always important for what you are trying to do.